# Spring: circular dependencies on constructor\setter injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I've read that `circular dependencies` are caused by `setter` injection. So I tried to check it by my own. And it appears that I can reproduce `circular dependency` only with `constructor` injection (see code below).

So the questions:

1. Can I accomplish `circular dependency` with `setter` injection?
2. How to resolve `circular dependencies` at code below?

   ```
   public class AConstr {

     private final BConstr b;

     public AConstr(BConstr bConstr) {
       System.out.println("AConstructor:: constructor");
       this.b = bConstr;
     }
   }

   public class BConstr {

     private final AConstr a;

     public BConstr(AConstr aConstr) {
       System.out.println("BConstructor:: constructor");
       this.a = aConstr;
     }
   }

   <bean id="aConstr" class="pack.bean.AConstr">
      <constructor-arg ref="bConstr"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="bConstr" class="pack.bean.BConstr">
      <constructor-arg ref="aConstr"/>
   </bean>
   ```

Comment: circular dependencies can be worked around with setters it isn't the cause. The cause is the fact that AConstr need BConstr and vice versa. This will be visible when using constructors not setters but either way you have a circular dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Circular dependency are cause by constructor injection only. In this your example you can use setter instead of constructor.

1. In case of Constructor injection, It will come to constructor say here `AConstr` and again it will see that `BConstr` has to be injected to before executing the `AConstr` it will go to `BConstr` and try to create object of `BConstr`.
2. Now when it will control will come to `BConstr` 's constructor then it will find dependency 'AConstr'. And this will create the Chain which is never ending.
3. During Setter injection inorder to inject an object it will create that object. So no problem if you have setter injection.
4. So when you call

   ```
    context.getBean("aConstr");
   ```

It will create an object of `aConstr` first then setter injection is called further injecting the dependency as `bConstr`.

Comment: Yes, but I mean resolve that problem still using constructor injection. For example, by using one of bean's callbacks (something like `afterPropertiesSet`). Is it possible?

Comment: Unnecessary why to increase code.It is recommended to use setter in case of CircularDependency and I am not sure that we can deal that afterPropertySet because afterPropertySet is called after constructor is executed I am not 100% sure about that.Check once.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways of injecting dependencies with Spring `@Autowired`: by **field** or by **constructor**.

If you have the following layers:

- RestController
- Service
- JpaRepository
- Entity

With the following bindings:

- 1 *RestController* is bound to the associated *Service* only
- 1 *Service* only use the associated *JpaRepositories* to manage the associated *Entities*
- To interact with *Entities* which are out of the service's functional scope, a *Service* uses other *Services*.

> ```
> FooController       BarController
> +                   +
> |                   |
> +                   +
> FooService<-------->BarService
> +                   +
> |                   |
> +                   +
> FooJpaRepository    BarJpaRepository
> +                   +
> |                   |
> +                   +
> FooEntity           BarEntity
> ```

Thus, it's normal that 2 *Services* can depend from each other (directly or not), and that's why you can break the circular dependency:

- with `@Autowired` on **fields** instead of on **constructor** in one of your Service
- Or just adding `@Lazy` before a constructor parameter.

here is what Spring suggests: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-dependencies

On the other hand, a *Service* (or directly a *JpaRepository*) should be injected to *RestControllers* by **constructor**. In that case a circular dependency would be an architecture problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late for an answer, but better late than never:

If you carefully read the article you will find out that probably your design is wrong:
http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/

Setter injection will only hide it from you.